# why I can't delete paragraph?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to delete the paragraph that jquery create when I click the paragraph.

```
<p class="test">cutsom event</p>
<button class="clcik">click</button>
```

jquery:

```
$(function () {
"use strict";

$(".test").on("click", function () {
    $(this).hide();
});

$("button").on("click", function () {
    $("<p>delet this paragraph</p>").insertAfter($(this));
});

$("p").on("click", function () {
    (this).hide();
});
});
```

update:
@LinkinTED solved it, but dose there best practice for for that code?

Comment: @user2486 class != event

Comment: @user2486 I don't understand? explain.

Comment: @akram `clcik` is misspelled. It probably doesn’t affect your JavaScript code, but just so you know.

Comment: $(".click").click(function(){
var p = $("<p>deleat this</p>")
$("body").append(p);
$(p).click(function(){
$(this).remove();
})
})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function will work on the paragraphs that are static in the page. However the dynamic added paragraphs won't. You'll need to bind the function on a static element.

```js
$(function () {
  /* obsolute while the last function is the same 
  $(".test").on("click", function () {
    $(this).hide();
  });*/

  $("button").on("click", function () {
    $("<p>delet this paragraph</p>").insertAfter($(this));
  });

  $(document).on("click", "p", function () {
    $(this).hide();
//  ^------ you forgot the $ here
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="test">cutsom event</p>
<button class="click">click</button>
```

Answer (score 6):

When you call this:

```
$("p").on("click", function () {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

your paragraph doesn't exist yet, so this doesn't actually do anything.

You can do `$('body').on('click','p', function(){})` instead

Comment: console said this Uncaught TypeError: "p".hide is not a function
when i put this
`$('body').on('click', 'p', function () {
        ("p").hide();
    });`

Comment: You are forgetting the `$` (again) `$("p").hide();`